# Was the transition of the descendants of Rígr into the family of Dan a peaceful one or a violent one?

Tags: norse

The [Rígsþula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%ADgs%C3%BEula) (found [here](http://www.archive.org/stream/elderorpoeticedd01brayuoft#page/216/mode/2up)) ends with a crow giving ominous council to Kon(r), son or Jarl, son of Rígr. The crow seems to urge him to fight Dan and Damp (also spelled "Danp"), supposedly Danish kings. On that note, the poem abruptly ends.

However, as suggested by the Skjöldungasaga and the Ynglinga saga, descendants of Rígr married into the ruling families of Denmark, and thus took control.

These are said to be the only tales of Rígr, but I would think that Dan/Danp show up somewhere else, possibly as genuine historical figures, and there might be a mention of Konr, given that his name led to the term *konungr*, meaning "king".

In any other sources, is a mention of Konr associated with a peaceful transition of power or a violent one, involving battles (as the crow advised)?

Answer (score 3):

I know someone else is going to come along behind me who knows a whole lot more about Denmark, but I think Rigsthula is more about establishing the social order than any real kings, or ancestors of them. However, [this paper](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/alvismal/10rigr.pdf) might help you out.